# hapijs h2o2 protocol not supported

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, webserver, hapi.js

I have a webserver using https that uses [h2o2](https://github.com/hapijs/h2o2) to proxy /api/* requests to my api server which uses http. Both servers are built on the [HapiJS](https://hapijs.com/) framework.

From the /login page, a user can submit authentication data to /api/authenticate, from which it returns a JWT cookie and (what I'm stuck on) redirects the user to / (or any page really).

The request successfully makes it through the proxy, and as long as I just use `h.response` instead of `h.redirect` the generated token makes it back to the client.

When I use `h.redirect` with a relative url such as `/images/background.png` I get `404: not found`.
When I use `h.redirect` with a full url such as https://example.com/ I get `Protocol "https:" not supported. Expected "http:"`. Even if I enter the url http://example.com/ (which redirects to https://example.com/) it still restructures the request into an https request.

Using a relative url would be lovely, but at least getting the redirect to work with a full url is a must.

I tried switching the api server to https (although I thought it was normal to keep it http?) but the cert is only valid for example.com, not the ip. I'd prefer not to re-sign the cert with the ip as an alt. I want to stick with http for the api server, but I'm not exactly sure what to do to make it work. Any ideas or advice is greatly appreciated.

I'm using hapi 17.5.1 for both servers and h2o2 8.2.1

`TypeError [ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL]: Protocol "https:" not supported. Expected "http:"
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:109:11)
    at Object.request (https.js:272:10)
    at internals.Client._request (webpack:///./node_modules/h2o2/node_modules/wreck/lib/index.js?:192:24)
    at options.beforeRedirect (webpack:///./node_modules/h2o2/node_modules/wreck/lib/index.js?:241:38)
    at Object.options.beforeRedirect.options.beforeRedirect (webpack:///./node_modules/h2o2/node_modules/wreck/lib/index.js?:100:134)
    at ClientRequest.onResponse (webpack:///./node_modules/h2o2/node_modules/wreck/lib/index.js?:239:24)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:546:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:109:17)`

Comment: For now (until I figure out what's wrong) I'm using h.response.code(303). It doesn't automatically redirect but I'm sure that will be easier to figure out than my original problem.